# Server side code not recognized in javascript OnClientClick function

Tags: javascript, .net, server-side

**UPDATE:  I simplified my code to just try to pass the parameter "1" in the onClientClick. The problem is that even that doesn't work because it translates/encodes my quotation marks so the javascript doesn't see it. I'd rather not add this on server side. Is there any way to pass a parameter as simple as the number 1 to a OnClientClick function?**

I want to simply do this on the .aspx page:

```
 <asp:Button onClientClick="return ValidateFile('1');" ID="btnUploadNominatorPDF" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

BUT, the page encodes the quotation marks and the Javascript does not run.

Comment: One solution is to assign that onclick through server side. I always had problems getting to work what you are doing.

Comment: ok, before your response, I simplified my code to just try to pass the parameter "1" in the onClientClick. The problem is that even that doesn't work because it translates/encodes my quotation marks so the javascript doesn't see it. I'd rather not add this on server side. Is there any way to pass a parameter as simple as the number 1 to a OnClientClick function?

Comment: trevoray, try using System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(). Can you post your server side code you tried

Comment: @BlueChameleon I'm not using server side code at this point. I'm just trying to pass a parameter in my OnClientClick function on the .aspx page. I'd rather not have to add anything to my server side code for this function. Is it not possible to simply add a "1" parameter to a OnClientClick function to the ASP Button on my aspx page without adding it on server side?

Comment: Just to be clear: That `ValidateFile` method, is that a javascript function or a method in your aspx (-codebehind)? If javascript, would number `1` work, as opposed to the string `'1'` you have now? If server side, then this will not work this easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just try to pass a paramater to `OnClientClick` event on aspx page, you should use attribute that `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` or optionally `OnClientClick="ValidateFile('1'); return false;"`

Sorry, I don't have any idea about encode issue.